# How to assign a value to variable inside subscription?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have Ionic 4 angular project, I need to assign value while reading inside subscribe. However I could not do that. I know there are several Questions and Answers related to mine. However none of them is working for me. Here is the my code and I tried so far. Any comments, any help is appriciated. Thank you very much.`

## Service.ts

```
  public loggedChecker: any;
  private lofff = new Subject<any>();

    postLoginToServer (password, email) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let postData =  {
     password: password,
     mail: email
 }
 console.log("8888888888888888888888888888888");

    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", postData, { observe: 'response'} )
      .pipe(map(data =>  this.loggedChecker =(data.body)));

      console.log(this.loggedChecker,"0330303333333333"); //undefined

      return this.loggedChecker+"";
}
```

And here is the another I  try

```
  postLoginToServer (password, email) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let postData =  {
     password: password,
     mail: email
 }
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", postData,{observe: 'response'})
      .subscribe(data => {
         
        this.loggedChecker =(data.body);
        
        this.textToDisplay = (data.body);
        this.lofff.next(data);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

    console.log(this.lofff,"logged checker");
    
    return this.loggedChecker+"";
    }
```

Here is the page.ts

## Page.ts

```
 logForm(){    
   
   console.log(this.fineService.postLoginToServer(this.passwordUser, this.email));
}
```

Both of  them are not working. Thank you.

Comment: So you're not able to see the data when you use the second code?

Comment: this.loggedChecker =(data.body) in this way, I editted question sorry, I made lots of changes,  I forget to put there

Comment: that should be `this.loggedChecker = data.body;`

Comment: I have tried it

Comment: when it's assigned you cannot return it inside the subscribe block or in the function as you did in the 1st code block. You should return `this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/post", postData,{observe: 'response'})` and then subscribe to it wherever you want.

Comment: I am trying to assign global variable a value inside of subscribe when I tried to console.log of the this variable outside of subscribe it prints undefined.

Comment: Are you sure data.body contains any data?

Comment: try `const response = await this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", postData,{observe: 'response'});` and then use `response` varable to do things, alternatively `this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", postData,{observe: 'response'}).then(result => { //do something }).catch(error => console.log(error));`

Comment: @MedaiP90 'await' expression is only allowed within an async function.

Comment: Yes I am sure that data.body contains data

Comment: @MedaiP90 how to import then ?

Comment: @ozer `async postLoginToServer (password, email)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand you are trying to assign a class property named `loggedChecker`.
This is what you should do:

```
  postLoginToServer (password, email) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let postData =  {
     password: password,
     mail: email
    }
    this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/login", postData,{observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(tap(data => {
        this.loggedChecker =(data.body);
        this.textToDisplay = (data.body);
        this.lofff.next(data);
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
      }));
    }
```

tap(import from rxjs) operator will not change the data but can be used to do things like what you're trying to do.

**UPDATE:**
You should change your logForm function.

```
 logForm(){    
   console.log(this.fineService.postLoginToServer(this.passwordUser, this.email));
}
```

should be

```
     logForm(){    
       this.fineService.postLoginToServer(this.passwordUser, this.email).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
       })
    }
```

because the HTTP request will return an observable and you will get its value when you subscribe to it.

Comment: It still print undefined.

Comment: where are you calling `postLoginToServer`? where are you printing the result? Note that since this is asynchronous if you try to print the value before you get the response it will be undefined.

Comment: I am calling it from page.ts

Comment: Update the question...add page.ts to it

Comment: I did, I added the page.ts

Comment: What should be the return type of "postLoginToServer"

Comment: it gives ````TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at LoginPage.logForm (login.page.ts:29)````

Comment: Thank you very much @Ramesh it works as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a callback function while calling the post request and since JS is non blocking. below lines will be excuted without waiting for the subscribe function call. hence you are getting undefined.

try console logging inside subscribe function or make the service function as async for your flow to wait until request is processed.

Comment: I am  trying to pass this value to the page.ts, thats why I need this

Comment: then try getting loff subject from this service and subscribe to "lofff" subject from page.ts. in service function log it try  this.lofff.subscribe(data ->  console.log("logged checker"));